# How can I do this simple search?

Tags: hibernate-search

I have a web app build with Hibernate.
In one page, I have one submit button with 5 inputs

- field1
- field2
- field3
- field4
- field5

When all the inputs are null, I make a simple query

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from MyTable");
```

but when I have at least one input not null, I must create the search query. Let's say, the field1 is not null:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from MyTable where field1= :field1");
query.setParameter("field1", field1);
```

But I need to check every single input and I need to create the query String based on this thing.

What is the smartest, easiest way to create the search query?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Criteria-Query instead:

```
Criteria criteria = hibernateSession.createCriteria(YourClass.class);
```

And then add a Criteria to your query based on every field:

```
if(fieldValue1 != null) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("FieldProperty1", fieldValue1))
}

if(fieldValue2 != null) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("FieldProperty2", fieldValue2))
}

...
```

Of course, that will only work if you use the native hibernate API instead of the JPA-API.

Comment: Upvoted this as it's correct, but if those input fields are free text as typed by the webapp user you might want to use the FullText Search API provided by Hibernate Search.